# Find cuboids from a list of indexes

Tags: python

I have a list of indexes (3 dimensions) that represents the location of one or more cuboids in a 3 dimensional domain (in the the following `nx, ny, nz = 35, 35, 45`).

I try to find the origin and the size of these cuboids (or at least one of the possibilities of distribution of these cuboids) from this list of indices.

For example, with the following list of indexes : [cuboids](https://perso.univ-lemans.fr/%7Ecdesjouy/SO/cuboid_without_hole.npy)

I can correctly find the following two cuboids:

```py
origin : (0, 3, 3)
size: (3, 29, 39)

origin : (22, 11, 9)
size: (3, 13, 27)
```

with the code below :

```py
bounds = [_np.unique([0, *(_np.where(abs(_np.diff(pcc[:, i], axis=0)) > 1)[0] + 1), pcc.shape[0]]) for i in range(3)]
#print(bounds)

while all(len(b) > 1 for b in bounds):

    x = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in _it.groupby(pcc[bounds[0][0]:bounds[0][1], 0])]
    y = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in _it.groupby(pcc[bounds[1][0]:bounds[1][1], 1])]
    z = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in _it.groupby(pcc[bounds[2][0]:bounds[2][1], 2])]
    #print('x:', x)
    #print('y:', y)
    #print('z:', z)
        
    origin = x[0][0], y[0][0], z[0][0]
    size = len(x), len(y), len(z)

    print(f'origin : {origin}\nsize: {size}\n')

    bounds = [b[int(_np.argwhere(b == bounds[0][1])):] for b in bounds]
```

The problem is that when I have a cuboid with a "hole", for example in the middle, the program will have to find four cuboids to have a correct description of the domain.

For example, the code find these cuboids :

```py
origin : (0, 3, 3)
size: (3, 29, 39)

origin : (22, 8, 3)
size: (3, 19, 28)
```

with this index list : [cuboids with hole](https://perso.univ-lemans.fr/%7Ecdesjouy/SO/cuboid_with_hole.npy)

which is wrong because the second cuboid has a hole in the middle. This area of the domain should therefore be represented by 4 cuboids (around the hole) to have a correct description.

When we look carefully at the `x`, `y`, and `z` variables, we can see that in some places there is a discontinuity. But I have a hard time to find a simple solution to take into account this problem.

Comment: Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time tearing my hair out, I have this solution to propose that seems to give consistent results:

```py
import numpy as _np


def consecutives(data, stepsize=1, coords=True):
    """ Search consecutives values in data. """

    idx = _np.r_[0, _np.where(_np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0] + 1, len(data)]
    splits = [data[i:j] for i, j in zip(idx, idx[1:])]

    if coords:
        consec = _np.array(list(_it.chain(*[(s[0], s[-1]) * s.size for s in splits])),
                           dtype=_np.int16).reshape(data.size, 2)

    confs = sorted(list(set((s[0], s[-1]) for s in splits)))

    if coords:
        return confs, consec

    return confs


def unique(data, keys=None):
    """ Return unique elements of data """
    if not keys:
        keys = data.T[::-1]
    else:
        keys = [data[:, i] for i in keys]
    sorted_data = data[_np.lexsort(keys), :]
    row_mask = _np.append([True], _np.any(_np.diff(sorted_data, axis=0), 1))
    return sorted_data[row_mask]


def locations_to_cuboids(coordinates):

    coordinates = (coordinates[0].astype(_np.int16),
                   coordinates[1].astype(_np.int16),
                   coordinates[2].astype(_np.int16))

    z_confs, z_consec = consecutives(coordinates[2])
    z_coords = _np.concatenate((z_consec,
                                coordinates[0][:, _np.newaxis],
                                coordinates[1][:, _np.newaxis]), axis=1)
    z_coords = unique(z_coords)
    z_indices = [0, *_np.cumsum([len(list(value)) for key, value
                                 in _it.groupby(zip(*z_coords[:, :2].T))])]
    z_groups = [z_coords[i:j, 2:] for i, j in zip(z_indices, z_indices[1:])]

    cuboids = []
    # Search cuboids in all groups
    for z_conf, z_group in zip(z_confs, z_groups):

        y_confs, y_consec = consecutives(z_group[:, 1])
        y_coords = _np.concatenate((y_consec,
                                    z_group[:, 0][:, _np.newaxis]), axis=1)
        y_coords = unique(y_coords)

        y_indices = [0, *_np.cumsum([len(list(value)) for key, value
                                    in _it.groupby(zip(*y_coords[:, :2].T))])]
        y_groups = [y_coords[i:j, 2] for i, j in zip(y_indices, y_indices[1:])]

        for y_conf, y_group in zip(y_confs, y_groups):
            x_confs = consecutives(y_group, coords=False)
            cuboids.extend([{'origin': (i[0], j[0], k[0]),
                            'size': (i[1] - i[0] + 1, j[1] - j[0] + 1, k[1] - k[0] + 1)}
                            for i, j, k in [(x, y_conf, z_conf) for x in x_confs]])

    return cuboids
```